# How to pass string as argument to a C macro

Tags: c, macros

I've one string array `char version[][8] = {"new", "old", "latest", "oldest", "ancient"}`;

and I've one macro

```
#define FS(file, attr) \
        filesys(file, file_ ##attr## _ops) \
```

How could I pass members of `version` of string array into the FS macro ?

Comment: Easier to make version like this: `const char *version[] = {"new", "old", "latest", "oldest", "ancient"};`

Comment: well, you cannot use strings to create variable names. The inverse is possible, though

Comment: If you want to work with files called `file_new_ops`, `file_old_ops`, etc., then you should perhaps consider using `sprintf()`. [Preprocessor string concatenation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/and-operators-in-c/) knows nothing about runtime variables.

Comment: There are some possibilities to do magic with pre-processor, though rarely clean and useful. However, you will have to talk more about the desired effect. E.g. how do you intend to use the macro? It is e.g. possible to make a macro which takes a number between 0..4 and ends up in a string with the words in your array, though not by accessing the array. Show more about what you want to actually do, then there might be a way.

Comment: The `##` operator cannot be used to combine a string with other symbols.  The argument must be a fragment of an identifier, and it must be used to connect otherfragments of an identifier to make a longer identifier.  You could use `FS("filename", filename)`; you cannot pass `FS("filename", version[0])` or `FS("filename", "old")`, etc.  Remember, the C preprocessor runs before the compilation starts; it cannot create a different name on each iteration of a loop, amongst other issues.

Comment: However, also have a look here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Macros are compile time and the compiler will no be able to splice the strings the way you want. Instead, try using `strcat()`, just don't forget that you need to keep track of how large your string arrays are.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use any C features in the macros as proprocessor does not know anything about the C and the C language.

Bear in mind that it is compile time token substitution.

Use normal functions instead